# How to clone or create a new copy of Map in java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, deep-copy

```
Map<String, WriteToFileColumnsModel> temp = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(inputMap);
temp.keySet().removeAll(targetMap.keySet());
targetMap.putAll(temp);

targetMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(inputMap);

targetMap.putAll(inputMap);

inputMap.forEach(targetMap::putIfAbsent);

for (Map.Entry<String, WriteToFileColumnsModel> entry : inputMap.entrySet()) {
        targetMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

I checked all the related questions on Stack Over Flow and tried the above possible ways. When I do any of the above way, new instance isn't created. When I alter targetMap, inputMap is altered too.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to create a new map with the same key value pairs from the existing map. But when I alter the new map, existing map shouldn't be altered

Comment: Mumble mumble. Get your terms straight - when you create a new map and then addAll(sourceMap) you *have* a new map. There is no way this doesn't work (as you claim). What *probably* happens is that you alter *objects* in the map, which are *of course* the same objects in the copied map. If you want copies of the objects *in* the map, you have to make copies for *each object* yourself.

Comment: So you mean the values are the same instances as of the existing map?

You are right. I was altering the value in the new map

Comment: Then you need a way to make copies of each object. This can range from simple to nearly impossible, depending on your WriteToFileColumnModel implementation. The process is called *deep clone*.

Comment: What is wrong with `Map newMap = new SomeKindOfMap(oldMap)`?  If you don't change the contents of the key and value Objects, which you probably shouldn't anyway, that will work.  Not sure what is your issru.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing altering *the map* with altering *the objects in the map*.

**First and foremost:** I *rarely* need to do this. Complex objects, like any called `Model`, rarely should be copied. It may be better to just pass the map around directly, *or* write a wrapper class that has better control over how its data can be accessed or modified.

You need a deep copy, which means the classes in the map - `String` and `WriteToFileColumnsModel` - need to support their own clone operation. Actually, this is a half-lie - `String` is immutable so using a shallow copy is fine, since it can never change anyway.

As a simpler example consider a class

```
class Person {
    public String name; // can be altered
}
```

And a

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Person("Bob"));
```

And you try to copy it

```
List<Person> otherPeople = new ArrayList<>(people);
```

And alter one...

```
people.get(0).name = "Sue";
```

And get the other one...

```
System.out.println(otherPeople.get(0).name); // prints "Sue"
```

This is the problem you are having in your copy.

You need to copy each `WriteToFileColumnsModel` individually, assuming this is supported. You probably will have to manually do this for each item in the map (or use some Java 8 bullcrap).

Comment: That worked perfect :) Thank you so much

But its pain to create a new object instance :)

Answer (score 2):

To me, most of your solutions should work. However, I think the most straight forward way is this:

```
Map<String, WriteToFileColumnsModel> targetMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(inputMap);
```

I think there is another problem: You are changing the objects that are stored as value in the map. Since both maps point to the same objects, you change the value object for both maps at the same time.

Comment: Why the downvote? I explain the same problem as the upvoted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. It helped

Comment: Though this answer could use a little elaboration, no cause for downvoting without commenting why.  I've noticed lately that SO downvotes make no sense.  And wondering why I waste so much time here...